# Can I automatize pppoeconf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, internet-connection, ppp

I am a Ubuntu user (10.04 as of now), since I use it, over a year, I have to manually enter the command **$ sudo pppoeconf** everytime I turn on the computer and want to connect to the internet, the I click enter some times, enter my password of my internet provider, then I click enter some more times to have internet.

I have to do this boring work, 3 times a day, just now I am asking you if you know any way of automatizing this?

Thanks!

Rodrigo Alves Vieira.

Comment: This question will probably be better on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

1. Find another program similar to pppoeconf that runs in non-interactive mode
2. Create a shell/perl/whatever script to automate pppoeconf
3. Use the "expect" utility

See an [example](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/56066).

Answer (score 1):

No need to run pppoeconf all the time. After you have configured pppoe once, just use 'pon' to connect.